# How to expose multiple TCP Servers through one load balancer

Tags: kubernetes, tcp

I have multiple deployments which run pods which run TCP servers. These TCP servers listen all on port 9999

Currently each deployment has their own load balancer service, which results in a different IP for each deployment.

However I would like to have one IP address to expose the deployments and only distinguish by port.

So for example:

```
<public-ip>:9001 -> deployment 1
<public-ip>:9002 -> deployment 2
<public-ip>:9003 -> deployment 3
```

I have read about Ingress but the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress) state that

> An Ingress does not expose arbitrary ports or protocols. Exposing services other than HTTP and HTTPS to the internet typically uses a service of type Service.Type=NodePort or Service.Type=LoadBalancer.

So that seems to be not an option.

For context the kubernetes is hosted in azure in an vnet and only needs to be accessed from within this vnet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functionality ingress depends on the controller implementation that you are using. For example nginx ingress controller supports TCP/UDP proxy as documented [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/#exposing-tcp-and-udp-services)

The next example shows how to expose the service example-go running in the namespace default in the port `8080` using the port `9000`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  9000: "default/example-go:8080"
```

If TCP/UDP proxy support is used, then those ports need to be exposed in the Service defined for the Ingress.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
    - name: proxied-tcp-9000
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

- Create a Service of type NodePort for each deployment: In this case, each deployment will be accessible from outside the cluster using <any k8s node ip>:<specific port>
- Set up a an external reverse-proxy/loadbalancer (outside of the kubernetes cluster) that points to all the k8s nodes and configure it to accept traffic from ports 9001, 9002 and 9003 and forward it to  of a k8s nodes

Now, you can use <reverse-proxy/loadbalancer ip>:900[1,2,3] to reach your applications